# Python Gmail API making it easier the authentication process for users

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am developing a python program which uses the gmail api to access the email data.

I have successfully developed the tutorial program and I am able to access the gmail data and do a lot of interesting things.

At the moment, I have to get the .json file from the gmail account, modify the code, run it, and then ask the user to get a verification code from the web browser, to finally authenticate the app so it can start running.

Now, my question is: how can I make the authentication process easier for the end-user?

It seems to me like this process is during the development of the software, but what if I have finished my development process and I want to make the app commercially/freely available to other users so they can start poking around with it?

Isn't there a way to quickly modify my software to make that process easier for the end user?

Any kind of help is well received, sorry if this had been asked before.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about - the authentication process is controlled by Google so not much you can do there except maybe store the authentication token so as to not prompt the user again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment =). For example, if I want to sell this software (which is not the case, but it would make this explanation easier) do I have to ask my customers to get into their console developer, create a .json file, download it, modify the source code, and finally run the software? Isn't there a way to do all of that in a better way?